# If clause dependent on file input doesn't seems to work

Tags: python, if-statement

Can someone explain to me why in the following code the message `"Found an instance without object"` is not printed along with the output?

```
filename= "S1-ADL1.dat"

with open(filename, 'r')as data:
 for line in data:            
    valueList=line.split(' ')   
    print "valueList[247]"+valueList[247]
    print "valueList[249]"+valueList[249]        
    if valueList[247] == '0'  and valueList[249] == '0':
            print "Found an instance without object"
            continue
    elif valueList[247]==0 and valueList[249]!=0:
        valueList[247]=valueList[249]
        valueList[246]=valueList[248]                        
print filename+' is written'
```

The output I get is as follows

```
valueList[247]0
valueList[249]0

valueList[247]0
valueList[249]0

valueList[247]0
valueList[249]0

S1-ADL1.dat is written
```

As you can see there are instances where the if statement is satisfied but it does not print the message in the if clause.

Comment: can you give sample input content ??

Comment: Try e.g. `print "valueList[247] " + repr(valueList[247])` - there is probably whitespace you aren't seeing.

Comment: Try valueList[249].strip() may helps.

Comment: yes use `strip()` before `split(' ')` method

Comment: When I use repr() the output is follows. 
valueList[247]0
valueList[249]'0'
S1-ADL1.dat is written

but my input is as
0 87 975 -287 11 ... 5762 2685 1265 5858 2707 1134 6294 2663 1533 5789 2907 1447 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (one before the last digit) is the valueList[249] value. why does it have quotes around it?

Comment: @user77005: Can you check your input file, the quotes are present or not like `'0'` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the newline character hidden in the last result of the split. In each `line` you're reading you have something like this: `'x y ... z\n'`, so the last result of `split` contains `'z\n'` (e.g. `"0\n"`). Alternatively it happens that it is the `'\r'` character, or some of other whitespace characters.

Try using [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
valueList = line.strip().split(' ')
```

If it is possible that you have multiple other whitespace characters between pieces of you input you may try:

```
valueList = [v.strip() for v in line.split(' ')]
```

to remove them individually from each piece.

Also, your second condition is wrong. If you're not converting the pieces to `int` you should stay with strings:

```
elif valueList[247]=='0' and valueList[249]!='0':      # note the apostrophes
```

Comment: yes correct, second condition is not valid. always return False

Answer (score 0):

Agree with BartoszKP.

Use `strip()` method before `split(' ')` method.

Can can print valueList in your code and check List input by `print  "valueList:-"  valueList` ? So this will more clear to you.

I tested on some sample test case:

```
valueList:- ['q', '0', '0', '\n']
valueList[247]0
valueList[249]0
Found an instance without object
valueList:- ['q', '0', '0\n']
valueList[247]0
valueList[249]0
```

---

OR You can write `if condition` like following:

`if valueList[247][0] == '0'  and valueList[249][0] == '0':`